# NOT IN in SSRS TextBox

Tags: reporting-services

How can I write `NOT IN` in TextBox expression?

I must check if some field value not belong to some list of strings, and then do some work.

Example:

```
Iif(SomeField.Value NOT IN ('Text1', 'Text2'), DoSomething, nothing)
```

I wrote code like this and got error when previewing report, and error was :

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Iif' accepts this number of type arguments
```

How can I do this stuff?

Comment: Where is the list of strings? Is it a field in a dataset?

Comment: No, it is a comma-delimited custom list, which I define. Example: 'Test', 'Work'...

Answer (score 1):

Try this small piece of custom code that accepts a string array. Just paste it into the report code section of the report..

```
Public Shared Function ValueExists(ByVal arr() as string, checkVal as string)    
    Dim i As Long        
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)            
            If arr(i) = checkVal Then  

                return true
                Exit Function                    
            End If            
        Next i        
    return false    
End Function
```

Usage would involve splitting the string into an array using the `Split` function

like so:

```
=iif(Code.ValueExists(Split("Your,comma,separated,string,in,here",","),"StringYouWantToFind")
,"Your value exists"
,"your value does not exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the code like this:

```
Iif(SomeField.Value <> 'Text1' AND Field.Value <> 'Text2' , DoSomething, nothing)
```

Comment: That is not enough for me, because number of attributes can grow, and then my expression will be difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

I got this one in one report:

```
=iif(join(Parameters!Parameter1.Value,",") like "*" & Fields!Field1.Value & "*","Color1","Color2")
```

This instruction helps me to determine the fill colour of a cell inside a tablix, where:
Parameter1 is a multivalue parameter. 
"Join" lets me have a string with all selected values from a multivalue parameter, eg. "value1,value2,value3,value4"

Field1 is the field that contains the values filtered by Parameter1
Color1 is the color if the value of the cell is included in the selection of parameter
else Color2

works well